# Returning partial view in jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am have an issue returning a partial view in a jquery dialog.

The code to call the partial view works and it returns as expected. However, the close button doesn't seem to work after the call has been made. Visual Studio also has "DisplayPartialFaxEob" underlined with the green squiggly line stating I'm missing "," or ")".

This is the code in my View.

```
providereobDialog.dialog({

            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: true,
            height: 550,
            width: 900,
            title: 'Provider EOB Details',
            resizeable: false,
            open: function() {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("DisplayPartialFaxEob", "ProviderEobFax")", function() { 
                });
            },
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    alert('close');
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
});
```

This is the code for my Action controller

```
public ActionResult DisplayPartialFaxEob()

    {
        //Does some stuff here
        return PartialView("_ProviderFaxEob", eob);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Just a FYI that the PartialView is a form that has some basic mvc scaffolding. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a closing bracket after "ProviderEobFax")"

needs to be

```
$(this).load("@Url.Action("DisplayPartialFaxEob", "ProviderEobFax")"), function() {
```

Update :

Are the buttons returned in the view?  If so any prior jQuery will no longer work as the elements have disappeared and you have all new elements. You will need to rewire the buttons or use the live functionality.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Well I fixed the squiggly error by using $(this).load('ProviderEobFax/DisplayPartialFaxEob'); And it works now, however after returning the partialview and closing the dialog all the buttons in my view stop working. Not sure if returning the partialview is messing something.

Comment: Yes the buttons are being returned but all previous jquery functionality in the back view doesn't work after I display the partial. I will look into the live functionality, thanks

Comment: using live should fix that problem. As I said in the answer, the buttons that were wired up with jquery no longer exist and you have all new buttons that have not been wired up yet.

Comment: Would I need to use the live functionality for all my variables as well since they seem to have vanished as well? I'm beginning to think returning a partial in a dialog may not be the way to go.

Comment: you could load the partial into the page as a hidden div and jqDialog will manage displaying it and hiding it.